# find longest consecutive sublist from list using python

Tags: python-2.7

I have a list say `[1,3,4,5,2,7,8,9,11,10,9,8,7,6,7,8]` in this we can have sequence like `[1,3,4,5],[7,8,9,11], [11,10,9,8,7,6]` so i need to write a logic to find the longest sequence of sublist(last one in example). List would be positive integer but can be any order(asc,desc).

Ok here is my try to find ascending order sequence and probably is working:

```
l = [1,3,4,3,2,1,7,8,9,11,12,12,8,7,6,7,8]
ll = []
temp = l[0]
ll.append(l[0])
keyval = {}

for x in range(1,len(l)):
    #print (str(x)+ "  :"+str(l[x]))
    if l[x] >= temp :
      ll.append(l[x])
      temp = l[x]
      #print (ll)
    else:
      keyval[len(ll)] = ll
      ll=[]
      temp = l[x]

max_key = max(keyval.keys())
print (keyval[max_key])
```

output is :[7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 12]

But i dont find logic to integrate for desc order sequence. Pls help

Comment: And our own attempt? :)

Comment: You can learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Not able to think proper logic, I can post some program but that would not worthy for that.

Comment: stephen-rauch and Willen @ could you please take a look now.

Comment: Hi @Bimlesh, looking at your question history, you haven't accepted an answer yet. If any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution (although a pretty ugly one :-) :

```
def longest_consecutive(values, elem):
    global long
    if not values or values[-1] + 1 == elem:
        values.append(elem)
        if len(values) > len(long):
            long = values[:]  # shallow copy
    else:
        values = []
    return values

example = [1, 3, 4, 5, 2, 7, 8, 9, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 7, 8]
long = []  # modified by reducing function
longest = []
reduce(longest_consecutive, example, [])
longest.append(long)
reduce(longest_consecutive, example[::-1], [])  # [::-1] means reverse order
longest.append(long[::-1])  # result must be reversed too
print(max(longest))
```